# SparkSQL - Error in WHERE clause referencing a column with a space in its name. Backticks/Double-Quotes/Brackets don't work

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

Environment:  Spark Notebook using SparkSQL in Synapse Serverless.  Spark pool is using Spark 3.3

I'm getting errors trying to work with a column that has a space in its name.

The column name is **Account Code**

It seems the way to work with spaces in SparkSQL is  backticks.  Backticks work when referencing the column in the SELECT and JOINs. But not always in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE eb.`Account Code` = 'Emp_Bud_NSR.Headcount'
```

This errors:

```
Syntax error at or near 'Code': extra input 'Code'
```

I've tried

- `Account Code` (backticks) - error above
- "Account Code"  (double quotes) - Syntax error at or near '"Account Code"'
- [Account Code] (square brackets - Syntax error at or near '['

I tested removing the space in the column at the source - then everything works. So it's definitely the space.  And sure, better not to have spaces to begin with.

Oddly, I have another notebook that works, despite being a similar situation

```
WHERE lower(left(i.`level code`,1)) in ('g','s','a')
```

That works fine.  But if I change it to

```
WHERE i.`level code` = 'g'
```

It gets the same error. So it depends on the construction of the WHERE clause, if backticks work or not.

In say T-SQL, one can utilize columns with spaces fine. I'm trying to understand what I'm missing in Spark SQL.

Comment: Can you add which spark version please?

Comment: @Chris My spark pool is running 3.3

Comment: is the backing store for these tables files or ms sqlserver?  if so you may have hit: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21360 - it could be worth looking through the stack trace to see if you find MS sql driver errors.

Comment: @Chris Intersting!  The source is: A TempView, itself coming over via spark.read.jdbc() - that is aimed at a View in Synapse Serverless. That View, is hitting a CSV file on a datalake.  I almost said "no not sql server", but it's...kind of SQL Server. It's the Synapse Serverless endpoint, which behaves much like SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you are facing issue when you are Using the `WHERE` clause:

I have tried the below using the **pyspark** and **spark.sql**

I have column name called **Account Code** with space in the column name

I am creating new column using the `.withColumn` and applying alias and use it in the `WHERE` clause
And next applying the `WHERE` clause.

```
df_alias = df.withColumn("Account_Code", df["Account Code"])
result_alias = df_alias.filter(df_alias["Account_Code"] == "Ram  Prasad")
result_alias.show()
```

```
+------------+---+------------+
|Account Code|Age|Account_Code|
+------------+---+------------+
| Ram  Prasad| 25| Ram  Prasad|
+------------+---+------------+
```

You can use a subquery and then use it in the `WHERE` clause

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_df")
result_subquery = spark.sql("""
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *, `Account Code` AS Account_Code
        FROM temp_df
    ) AS subquery
    WHERE subquery.Account_Code = 'Ram  Prasad'
""")
result_subquery.show()
```

```
+------------+---+------------+
|Account Code|Age|Account_Code|
+------------+---+------------+
| Ram  Prasad| 25| Ram  Prasad|
+------------+---+------------+
```

You can create a `UDF` (User Defined Function).
Define a function to use the column name with spaces.Use the function in the `WHERE` clause

```
@udf(StringType())
def column_with_space(column):
    return column
result_function = df.filter(column_with_space(df["Account Code"]) == "Ram  Prasad")
result_function.show()
```

```
+------------+---+
|Account Code|Age|
+------------+---+
| Ram  Prasad| 25|
+------------+---+
```

Comment: Amazingly enough, it's still complaining about the space. I tried doing my FROM against a subquery where I aliased the column to have no spaces - same error as if the space were still there.   And, tried doing a temp view where I aliased the columns to have no spaces -  same error.  I haven't tried a UDF - I'm not a huge fan of incorporating a UDF into where clauses just the for complexity factory, but that's a good idea.

Comment: @NaveenSharma Thanks, but see my comment above: Aliasing did not work - Spark still sees the original space.  Even if I alias the column as NewNameEntierly, it will still error on the 'Code' portion that theoretically doesn't exist.  I don't consider a UDF as a reasonable solution.  The only reasonable solution I see is to remove the space at the source.